# extracting data from bika lims

Tags: plone

i am using bika lims to develop a lims . I am trying to maintain a universal lims say bikaA wherein I can store all possible information(list of all types of tests, their costs, containers) which can be used later for developing similiar subsystems bikaB, bikaC etc which will contain only subsets of the information stored in bikaA depending on the needs of the specific clients.

Basically I want to extract information from one universal lims to sub lims which are the actual end products.what I want to ask is:

1.How can I extract data from universal lims- bikaA and convert this data to different formats like csv.
2. how can this data be imported into child lims .

Answer (score 4):

Bika LIMS uses spreadsheets containing setup data (example [here](https://github.com/bikalabs/bika.lims/blob/958b56acf230c7633702c9a81708ffc6bab519c4/bika/lims/setupdata/test/test.xlsx)) which you can use to pre-configure the things you mentioned and quite a few more.  You can edit this sheet and re-import into each new LIMS instance.  You can also import subsections of this spreadsheet into an existing bika.lims site.  The importer does have a few rough edges (most notably, the error messages during import are not very easy to read), but it works quite well for us.

Right now there is no good solution to do exactly what you want, but there are export and import scripts located [here](https://github.com/bikalabs/bika-export-import).  They are simple command line scripts, and they don't use any Plone migration tools and addons.  They could serve as a starting point.  It's planned to clean these up and include them in Bika LIMS as soon as there is enough interest or time.

As Luca Fabbri already said, you can use the Bika mailing lists (or slack channel) if you have specific questions - you might get a faster response over there.

hope this helps